# Cant figure out how to make this nav tab a dropdown menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I just haven't been able to figure out the syntax
I am trying to have a drop-down menu appear when I click on the second button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=
  "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity=
  "sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin=
  "anonymous" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Font Awesome  -->

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/926120954b.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<!-- My CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">


</head>

<body>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1g" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

<!-- ****BEGIN THE DROPDOWN TAB-->

<li role="Presentation" class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="Pet" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Community <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>




<!-- ***END  THE DROPDOWN TAB  -->


  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Help</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pets for Sale</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Services</a></li>

</ul>








 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My first attempt at making a nav menu.    (For some reason, I am unable to submit this question without providing "details" so please forgive this meaningless text here)

Comment: I'm about done with this.  I ask a question, it gets down voted.  Sorry I'm new to this but if my questions get down votes because I'm not "uber-cool" like "you guys" I'll find other resources.  Its no problem really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the call to bootstrap's javascript library which is needed for the hamburger nav. Try adding this after you add the jquery reference (i.e. `<script src="...jquery.min.js"...`)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For more information, see the Bootstrap documentation page: [*Getting Started*](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), as  well as the updated code snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity=
  "sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin=
  "anonymous" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Font Awesome  -->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/926120954b.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<!-- My CSS  -- >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">-->
<!--end head: </head>  start body:<body>-->

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1g" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

<!-- ****BEGIN THE DROPDOWN TAB-->

<li role="Presentation" class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="Pet" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Community <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

<!-- ***END  THE DROPDOWN TAB  -->
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Help</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pets for Sale</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Services</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing this out.  I added it in just before my </html> tag at the end, and also tried it just before the in the                                    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->      Comment and Still no Luck.

Comment: @ZeroCalm try putting that script tag just after the script tag for the jQuery source- it shouldn't go outside the `<body>` tag...